# pd.read_csv sep ";" not working. tricky dataset

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, separator

I tried different stack overflow solutions using `pd.read_csv` for this file.
When I use Excel to text to and use `";"` as delimiter in Excel, it gives exactly the output I need.

[image: desired excel output:]

data:

| 'Balance Sheet;"'Package / Number";"Package Type";"Instrument";"Counterparty";"Opening Date";"Value Date";"Maturity Date";"'Nominal Amount";"'Interest Rate";"CCy";"'Funding Type";"Nominal Amount Local";"Interest Rate Local";"'Maturity Year";"'Maturity Quarter";"Tenor";"Tenor Range";"Date Basis" |
| --- |
| Asset Finance;"2.915.239";;"IRS-FIX-TO-FLOAT";"X_SEL";"03/27/2019";"03/29/2019";"08/29/2023";"-20.000.000.000";"1 |
| Asset Finance;"2.915.239";;"IRS-FIX-TO-FLOAT";"X_SEL";"03/27/2019";"03/29/2019";"08/29/2023";"20.000.000.000";"2 |
| Asset Finance;;;"IRS-FIX-TO-FLOAT";;"03/27/2019";"03/29/2019";"08/29/2023";;;;"Payer Swap";"20.000.000.000";"-1 |

Code:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(path2, sep='";"',engine='python')

df = df.apply(lambda x: x.replace('"','')) --\> doesnt seems to be working
```

The output columns are not split correct. It should be per above column 0: Balance Sheet, 1: Package / Number, 2: 'Package Type etc.. total 19 columns

pandas output:

[image: pandas output]

If there is any other work around solutions, pls tell. Thanks!

Comment: Your CSV has issues. Not all columns/values are clearly separated by `";"`. If you notice the last row in your image, multiple columns are clubbed as first column value, and "Interest Rate" column's value is in "Instrument" column so on.

Comment: Hi Azhar! Yes indeed. Any thoughts on how to process this data instead? As this data is as-is extracted from system which I can’t change beforehand. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use only sep=";" to correctly split columns. Add quotechar='"' to tell pandas that " is a quote character and should not be part of value.

```
df = pd.read_csv(path2,sep=';', quotechar='"',engine='python')
```